# Version 8.2 difficulties

Tags: netbeans, import, netbeans-8

I upgraded to version 8.2 and my projects list disappeared. When I pointed to the folder where my java files are located, Netbeans cannot find a project file. However, in the folder reside my 2 java files and a form file. 
Admittedly, I do lack a bit of Netbeans experience, and for the life of me, I cannot figure out how to import these files into a project - and be able to work with the form. Can anyone give me a pointer on how to resurrect my project?

Edited at recommendation:
When I selected "Open Project" and entered the path to where my files are located "/Users/robertbray/Documents/Robert/NetBeans/numberaddition/" In the "Project Folder" pane, nothing appears, as if the project does not exist.  So, playing around this evening, I used the "Open File" method and entered the path "/Users/robertbray/Documents/Robert/NetBeans/numberaddition", now I am able to see my source files (NumberAdditionUI.java, NumberAdditionUI.form, and GraphPanel2.java) and I can open them, including the form (design). However, I cannot determine how to convert this to a project file so I can build and run the code - these options are greyed out.

Comment: As it stands your question is too vague. What does _"When I pointed to the folder where my java files are located"_ actually mean? What did you actually **do** in NetBeans to attempt to recover the lost projects? Be very specific; detail the actions you took, step by step.

Comment: Thank you for the very constructive feedback!

Comment: please format your question properly, e.g. code, quotes should use its formatting respectively.

Comment: OK. Is **numberaddition** the name of your NetBeans project that you are trying to open? If so, then what happens if you do **File > Open Project...** then navigate to directory **/Users/robertbray/Documents/Robert/NetBeans**? (Don't just type the name of the project directory you think you need - use navigation to get there.) Is **numberaddition** shown as one of the projects you can open? If so, open it. If not, do you see any other projects that you could open?

Comment: Also, as a separate issue, have you successfully created a new project under NetBeans 8.2 yet? If not, spend two minutes verifying that you can. For Example: **File > New Project... > Java > Java Application >** click **Next >** etc. This is just to verify that your 8.2 installation is set up correctly.

Comment: @skomisa, yes I can create a project. And yes, "numberaddition" is the project, and when I use Navigation in the folder, there are no file entries in the dialog box to select the folder, none of the three files appear in "Open Projects" dialog. I switched to classic view with same result. As stated before, if I just open with "Open File" all the code is there, along with the form that went with it. What if I  open a new project and copy all of the original code into that, would the form be accessible as well?

Comment: OK. I don't know what caused your problem (except that a NetBeans upgrade would not touch any projects), but your proposal is a good workaround: create a new project and then copy the application files you created in the **numberaddition** project across to your new project. Also, FYI note that when you use the _Open Project_ dialog, NetBeans will only display directories containing valid NetBeans projects, so (for some unknown reason) **numberaddition** is not a valid NetBeans project. I'm not sure it's worth digging deeper to understand why at this stage  - just copy the files and move on.

Comment: @skomisa - Thank you, I will take this approach. The only concern is how I get the numberaddition.form imported into the new project - I really don't want to go through that pain again. Any ideas? Anyhow, I will forge ahead, and will research the blog to look for additional ideas. Again, much appreciated.

Comment: @RobertBray One other thing you could try: since **File > Open Project...** doesn't work, try **File > New Project... > Java > Java Project with Existing Sources... > Next > etc..**. It may not work either, but it only takes a minute to find out.

Comment: @skomisa.  Thank you for the suggestions - and, while I did not use the last suggestion, I was able to recover everything by opening a new project file, and dumping the original files into the directory, then renamed them (and a few tweaks internally for the new name). Everything is 100% once more!

Answer (score 1):

Since I had the original source files, I created a new project, then moved (and renamed) the original java class/form files into the "/src" directory. Of course I had to do some changes in the java files with the new name. As s test, I modified the form and rebuilt the project. Working as expected. Many thanks to @skomisa!